# Convert json string to list or map

Tags: java, json, gson

I get a json string in server side as follow

```
[     {"projectFileId":"8547",
       "projectId":"8235",
       "fileName":"1",
       "application":"Excel",
       "complexity":"NORMAL",
       "pageCount":"2",
       "targetLanguages":" ar-SA",
       "Id":"8547"
      },
      {"projectFileId":"8450",
       "projectId":"8235",
       "fileName":"Capacity Calculator.pptx",
       "application":"Powerpoint",
       "complexity":"NORMAL",
       "pageCount":"100",
       "targetLanguages":" ar-LB, ar-SA",
       "Id":"8450"
      }
]
```

I want to convert this string into an arraylist or map whichever possible so that I can iterate over it and get the field values.

Comment: Use a JSON parser.  There are about 20 to choose from, listed on the bottom of the page json.org (which is a good page to visit anyway, to learn the JSON syntax).

Comment: And that data is a JSON array containing two JSON objects.  This is equivalent to a Java List containing two Java Maps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GSON` library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Simply use [`Gson#fromJson()`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29) method to convert JSON string into Java Object.

sample code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("json.txt")));
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data = gson.fromJson(reader, type);

// convert back to JSON string from object
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

---

You can create a POJO class to convert it directly into List of POJO clas object to access it easily.

sample code:

```
class PojectDetail{
    private String projectFileId;
    private String projectId;
    private String fileName;
    private String application;
    private String complexity;
    private String pageCount;
    private String targetLanguages;
    private String Id;
    // getter & setter
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<PojectDetail>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<PojectDetail> data = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
```